# Only color lines that are between selected points - ggvis

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggvis

In the code below, for the mtcars dataset, if you click a point only the cars that have the same number of gears become red. As you can see, there are lines between cars of the same number of gears. What I would like to do is to make the lines red also. That is, if I select a point, the points with the same number of gear as well as the lines between them become red. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
library(ggvis)

lb <- linked_brush(keys = 1:nrow(mtcars), "red")


mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>%
  layer_points(fill := lb$fill, fill.brush := "red") %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  lb$input() %>%
  set_options(width = 300, height = 300) %>%
  layer_points(fill := "red", data = reactive(mtcars[mtcars$gear %in% mtcars[lb$selected(),]$gear, ]))
```